# How to call stored procedure by passing mapping variable $$date with source pre load using unconnect SP transformation in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I want to pre load my source using stored procedure. I already have a SP created in my database. I am using unconnected SP transformation,providing the CALL TEXT property as "example($$date)" and also selecting SP type property as Source Pre Load but my session is failing. When i pass the value like "example('20201012') then its working fine. But my requirement is to pass the parameterized variable. I cannot change the SP present in database in anyway and have to per load the source. Help needed.

Comment: can you pls try `example('$$date')` or `example("$$date")` ?

Comment: I am providing DATE as an input parameter for my SP present in database. While changing example($$date) to example('$$date')/example("$$date")/example(to_char($$date)) I am getting the following error: An error occurred executing the SP TM_6159 FnName: ExecuteSP -- error : bad date external representation "$$date"

Comment: Can you share both: Workflow log and Session log? It should be all clear there.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a datetime value through a stored procedure, the value must be in the Informatica date format and enclosed in double quotes. For example: proc("20201012")

When using a parameter, try proc("$$bus_date") or proc(to_char($$bus_date))

Comment: I am providing DATE as an input parameter for my SP present in database. While changing example($$date) to example('$$date')/example("$$date")/example(to_char($$date)) I am getting the following error: An error occurred executing the SP TM_6159 FnName: ExecuteSP -- error : bad date external representation "$$date"

Comment: Hi, I have also tried proc($$date), where my $$date is picked from the parameter file as 20200719. In the mapping , within parameters and variables option, i have set it as a string parameter. Kindly try that out aswell.